What does 'to skew mercurial' mean?
In episode 2* of the second season of Ted Lasso, there's a phrase: "I'm starting to realize that Ol' Blue Eyes might've skewed mercurial". Right before saying this, Ted mentioned a series of romantic relationships of Frank Sinatra. In the Russian subtitles, it's translated as он времени зря не терял ≈ he wasted no time. Is it correct? What does to skew mercurial actually mean?
* According to the wiki page, the episode's title is a reference to rock band Marillion's classic 1985 song "Lavender"


With that translation, "he wasted no time", which is a colloquial collocation that means to act without delay, to be quick to make a decision, perhaps the translators were focusing on the sudden change implied by skew.  Sinatra became fickle and inconstant -- an unfaithful lover.

https://www.nybooks.com/online/2022/01/19/language-is-the-game-ted-lasso/

I'm not great at facial recognition, but that picture doesn't look like Cristo Fernandez to me. On the other hand, it looks very similar to Freddy Mercury, right down to the tash.

@FumbleFingers the “proof” that the actor Tom Selleck is gay. I hope your tongue is firmly wedged in your cheek.

It really isn't relevant whether Sinatra was actually gay (or bi). He and his fellow ratpackers were all part of a Hollywood scene where some major players were gay, but would never have admitted it publicly for fear of jeopardizing their careers. Sinatra would have known of and associated with some of those "closet gays" for sure.

Also, if you're a bit older, 'wasted no time' sometimes means 'had sex outside of marriage', traditionally said about a new bride with a bump. (though I suspect every sentence in British English can be a euphemism)

Ted Lasso, a college American football coach from Kansas,  Midwest USA,  is hired as a manager (US coach) of a struggling British football club. While "skewed mercurial" might be a regional expression, it is more likely that it is the fruit of the writers’ imagination.

"You two are like Frank Sinatra and Ava Gardner, you know? Or Frank Sinatra and Mia Farrow. Or Frank and ... actually, you know what? I'm starting to realize that Ol' Blue Eyes might have skewed mercurial."

Frank Sinatra, nicknamed "Ol’ Blue Eyes", was famous not only for his warm, mellifluous voice on stage but also for the women he dated–and sometimes married–offstage. Lasso is only now realising how askew, volatile and unpredictable Sinatra‘s love life was. Mercury and mercurial are often used as metaphors to describe someone's eloquence, ill-temper, moodiness, and, in this instance, tempestuous love affairs.
In the eponymous TV show, Ted Lasso is respected and loved for his optimism and the inspirational talks held in the football dressing room (US locker room). Here are a few other quotes, cleverly combined with English idioms, that showcase the level of ingenuity and Midwestern charm Ted Lasso is known for.


“I think that you might be so sure that you’re one in a million, that sometimes you forget that out there you’re just one in 11”
“Living in the moment, it’s a gift. That’s why they call it the present.”
“I know we can’t fix every ache inside of us, but I shouldn’t have to pretend it’s not there either.”
“Be curious, not judgmental”
“Sam was more open than the jar of peanut butter on my counter.”


Merriam-Webster's definition for mercurial

1: of, relating to, or born under the planet Mercury
2: having qualities of eloquence, ingenuity, or thievishness attributed to the god Mercury or to the influence of the planet Mercury
3: characterized by rapid and unpredictable changeableness of mood a mercurial temper
4: of, relating to, containing, or caused by mercury

The Russian subtitle "he wasted no time" likely refers to the  sense of speed and impulsiveness in Sinatra's love life. However, it fails to capture the distorted and imbalanced nature that the term “skewed” alludes to.

If I wanted to suggest that Sinatra was taking after the Queen singer, I think a judicious capital letter might be in order - waxing Mercurial.

@MichaelHarvey It would be strange to suggest that Sinatra took after Freddie Mercury, since he was 31 years older and his public love affairs were largely over by the time Mercury was internationally known.  That type of reference might work if one was comparing Sinatra to the Shakespearian character Mercutio.

@Kirt - do you know what the idiomatic expression 'take after' means?

Wot? With the waxed (mercurial?!) moustache? I said before that I'm not great at face recognition, but that OP's picture looks more like Freddy Mercury than Cristo Fernandez. I've just googled "mercurial moustache", and for some reason Google gave me a line of pictures before the text hits. And the second picture was from the BBC - looking just like OP's pic to me, and captioned Freddie and his mercurial moustache. (I'm not making any of this up, I assure you! :)

@MichaelHarvey I believe so.  Yes, it does mean 'resemble' - but after carries a temporal connotation.  I could say a father resembles his son and vice versa.  I could say a son takes after his father.  But it is just not standard usage to say "That father really takes after his son."

@Kirt - My use seems to be mainly British. The resemblance is not necessarily purely physical. If Frank Sinatra (1915-1998) had grown a moustache and started acting flamboyantly homosexual, you could say that he was taking after Freddie Mercury (1948-1991). Take after in British English verb (intr, preposition) 1. to resemble in appearance, character, behaviour, etc 2. to follow as an example (Collins Dictionary).

@Kirt - (Take) 73 {take after ―}. a. To follow the example of; to imitate; hence, to resemble (a parent, ancestor, predecessor, superior, etc.) in nature, character, habits, appearance, or other quality. OED 2nd Ed 1989

@MichaelHarvey If British usage is different, then I cede, for I certainly have no context for that.  If Sinatra had grown a moustache before the career of Mercury, though, would you still say that he had taken after Mercury?  Your suggested definition even includes follow (not lead), to resemble (a parent, ancestor, predecessor) not (an offspring, descendent, successor).  It sure looks to me like one 'takes after' someone that came before, but if Brits don't use it that way, good on them.

@Kirt - you can follow, imitate, emulate, resemble, (etc) someone who came before, or someone who is here now.

@Kirt etc. Hello people, all this talk about Sinatra taking after (Freddie)  Mercury,  not physically but in their sexual preference,  has absolutely nothing to do with my answer. Please take your discussions to the poster who first sustained this position. Thank you! .

The verb skew here is being used in a way similar to its usage in statistics, where it means something like “display asymmetry” (check out this Wikipedia page).
Your example is comparable to things like

This cafe’s clientele skews artistic and intellectual

which means that the cafe’s typical patron is more likely to be an artist or an intellectual than is a person selected at random from the general public.
Thus to “skew mercurial” means to be more volatile or quick-tempered than the average person.
(And Old Blue Eyes is a moniker that was often applied to Frank Sinatra.)

"volatile or quick-tempered" is not a normal definition of "mercurial"; it refers to general (often emotional) changeableness, not merely being quick to anger. "volatile" alone could work I guess, but if you pair it with quick-tempered, the connotations point to someone who goes nuclear at the drop of a hat.

Skew in this sense is used to indicate an imbalance in composition, particularly in political polling: "skewed Democratic" or "skewed Republican", meaning with more than average Democratic or Republican Party support. It's commonly found in journalism, demographics, market research, etc.

Law firm PAC donations skewed Republican in 2016. Now, Dems have $1.6 mln lead. (Reuters, 2020)


Cubans and Venezuelans have historically skewed Republican and have powered GOP victories in the state [Florida] for figures such as Jeb Bush. (Vox, 2023)

It's also found outside of politics for other demographic information. You get e.g. "skewed younger", meaning having a larger number of young people than expected

This year, the Grammys have skewed younger (Pittsburgh Post-Gazette, 2013)


Yeah, well, I was hoping the female population down there - skewed younger than that. (Dark Ride, a 2006 horror film)

The Corpus of Contemporary English Usage also has "skewed low", "skewed left", etc, giving similar insight into composition.
So skewed mercurial is a playful variation on that kind of statistical analysis. It means there were a larger than expected number of mercurial people among his sexual partners, probably in the sense mercurial="characterized by rapid and unpredictable changeableness of mood". It's actually a bit of a twisted usage because you would normally say "Sinatra's partners skewed mercurial". Similarly, saying his partners "skewed younger" would mean he dated lots of younger women.

Hi! I upvoted your good answer! Thank you very much for your help!

OP has enquired

What does 'to skew mercurial' mean?
In episode 2 of the second season of Ted Lasso,

"In Ted Lasso (Season 2, Episode 2), the phrase 'skewed mercurial' is used to describe Frank Sinatra's tumultuous relationships. As Ted Lasso is from Kansas, this phrase might be a regional or colloquial expression.

Reference Merriam Webster
Synonyms of mercurial:
inconstant, fickle, capricious, mercurial, unstable mean lacking firmness or steadiness (as in purpose or devotion).


And the full dialogue from the episode of Ted Lasso:
You two are like Frank Sinatra and Ava Gardner, you know? Or Frank Sinatra and Mia Farrow. Or Frank and ... actually, you know what? I'm starting to realize that Ol' Blue Eyes might have skewed mercurial
https://www.npr.org/2021/07/30/1022210711/ted-lasso-recap-season-2-the-prodigal-beefcake

Ted calls Frank Sinatra 'Ol' Blue Eyes,' a nickname referring to Sinatra's blue eyes, but also affectionately implying age and experience (here in building up relationships)
By this dialogue 'Ol' Blue Eyes might have skewed mercurial,' Ted suggests Sinatra's relationships were marked by:

Unpredictability (mercurial)
Frequent changes (skewed).

The Russian subtitle 'he wasted no time' doesn't accurately convey the phrase's meaning.

Google defines skew as suddenly change direction or position.  It defines mercurial as subject to sudden or unpredictable changes of mood or mind.
I can't see how the combination would give he wasted no time.
With the context Ted mentioned about the series of romantic relationships of Frank Sinatra, I'm starting to realize that Ol' Blue Eyes might've skewed mercurial likely means Sinatra again changed his partner.
He wasted no time may be what was said next:

I'm starting to realize that Ol' Blue Eyes might've skewed mercurial.  He wasted no time.


I think it's an oblique reference to Queen's lead singer Freddy Mercury, who certainly presented as homosexual. As that linked Wikipedia article says, his flamboyant stage performances sometimes led journalists to allude to his sexuality.
It may be uncertain exactly what the cited line from Ted Lasso means, but I'm fairly sure it's suggesting that Sinatra might have been bisexual, or at least "prepared to experiment" in that area. It's a deliberately quirky whimsical "one-off, nonce" usage - essentially played for laughs, with little or no "truth value".
I certainly don't think there's any deliberate intention to allude to the dictionary sense of mercurial = fickle, changeable, unpredictable. Popular TV shows rarely use "literary, poetic" terms like that.

Looking more closely at the exact context, I now think the idea is that when the speaker is rattling off a list of Sinatra's romantic partners, fellow "rat packers" Dean Martin and Jerry Lewis come to mind. And this picture may be just whimsical tomfoolery, but you get the message...


I find it hard to believe the downvotes! I haven't watched it, but the relevant episode of Ted Lasso is even called Lavender (where as that link points out, "lavender scare" was a moral panic about homosexual people in the United States government which led to their mass dismissal from government service during the mid-20th century).

How can dating Marilyn Monroe, Lana Turner, and marrying Ava Gardner, Mia Farrow and  two other women in his life,  possibly suggest that F.Sinatra was a closet gay or bisexual? The term mercurial existed long before the late 1970s (i.e. Queen era)

@MariLouA In purely linguistic terms, the fact that the word mercurial was being used centuries before Freddy was born is irrelevant.  That's not a valid counter-argument.  For example, one could call a witty but zany romantic comedy with lots of word play and many plots twists and turns "pythonesque" and people could debate whether that was referring to the snake because of the plot twists or to  Monty Python because of the wit and zaniness, or referring to both.

@TimR and what about the many girlfriends he had and the four women he married in his lifetime. I mentioned that too. FF answer is literally based on the fact that the lead singer, Freddie Mercury, was/is a well-known to have been gay.

@Mari-LouA As I said, in purely linguistic terms...  I have no knowledge of Sinatra's private life.   Just pointing out the fallacy in your linguistic argument.

Like I said in my answer, the line is played for laughs. Any factual [in]accuracy regarding Mercury's or Sinatra's sexuality is largely irrelevant.

"… but I'm fairly sure it's suggesting that Sinatra might have been bisexual …"

That's the "literal" meaning of the utterance. My point was that the "ground truth" of the utterance is irrelevant, since it's just a line played for laughs.

"Nate's still coming down hard on young Will, this time for using lavender fabric softener on the team's laundry, which Nate claims will throw off the players.” Ted Lasso recap You should watch the show, I loved it. I thought it was very funny as well as being clever. P.S I didn't DV.

@Mari-LouA: I used a subtitle to find the timing offset, downloaded the episode from a torrent, got chatgpt to write me a script to extract from a few seconds around the cited text, and watched it. I still think my reading is correct - particularly given I've just googled frank sinatra romantic partners and without leaving the google homepage I got "AI Overview" Frank Sinatra had many romantic partners, including wives, actresses, and other women. It would be incredibly banal of the Ted Lasso character to be "starting to realize" that. But if he's thinking of Sinatra and the rat-pack...

Ted Lasso character is a guy who always sees the glass half full,  he is disarmingly charming. He believes "in believe", so his sudden shock realising that Ole Blue Eyes was a ladies' man is erm... believable. I think you're barking up the wrong tree, but keep barking maybe someone will listen in the end and "believe" in your answer.

Well, I'm not going to watch the whole episode just to get a better impression of the writers' approach, but if you like the show perhaps you could watch it to see if there's any other explanation for introducing lavender. I asked google "is will in ted lasso gay" and it said No, but Colin Hughes, a character in the Apple TV+ show Ted Lasso, is gay:
A footballer played by Billy Harris who comes out as gay in season 3, episode 3. Colin makes a passing comment about Grindr in season 2, and in season 3, he acknowledges his sexuality to journalist Trent Crimm. It's in the air, methinks.

This is the wrongest answer I've ever seen here, and, as our audience here is people who are kind of uncertain in English usage, I've thought it worth adding this comment telling them to not rely on anything in it.

@Mari-LouA I don't think FF is correct here, but to answer your question about how could a long list of female lovers imply that someone is gay or bisexual, in Hollywood it most certainly could.  A man hiding his true sexuality would absolutely have relationships with women, the more numerous, the more public, and the more "bombshell" the better.  The women would be considered beards.  I don't think that is what is happening in this case, but it is certainly a classic and recognizable pattern.

@Kirt: It's not about "a long list of female lovers imply that someone is gay or bisexual". It's about the fact that the character (a scripted actor, not a real person) has started a list of "famous names associated with Sinatra", where after the second one, the scriptwriter (and at least some viewers) might think of Sinatra and the (male) rat pack. Cue "oblique joke".
